# Уровни cxgrid, devexpress

Tags: delphi, devexpress

в cxgrid есть два уровня. Как развернуть все записи первого уровня? [image: вот мой грид]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ARecord: TcxCustomGridRecord;
i : Integer;
begin
     for I := 1 to Self.odsbs.RecordCount do
       begin
        ARecord := TcxGridTableController(grGrid1Level1.GridView.Controller).FocusedRecord;
        TcxGridMasterDataRow(ARecord).Expand(True);
         Self.grTableViewBSD.DataController.GotoNext;
       end;
       Self.grTableViewBSD.DataController.GotoFirst;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ARecord: TcxCustomGridRecord;
i : Integer;
begin
  i := 1;
    while i <= Self.ods1.RecordCount  do begin
      ARecord := TcxGridTableController(cxgrdlvlGrid1Level1.GridView.Controller).FocusedRecord;
      TcxGridMasterDataRow(ARecord).Expand(True);
      Self.cxgrdbndtblvwcxgrd1DBBandedTableView1.DataController.GotoNext;
      i := i +1;
      Application.ProcessMessages;
     end;
     Self.cxgrdbndtblvwcxgrd1DBBandedTableView1.DataController.GotoFirst;
end;
```

Comment: `Self.` - тут использовать не нужно. `Application.ProcessMessages;` - плохая идея. `cxgrdbndtblvwcxgrd1DBBandedTableView1` - ну и имя у объекта.. язык сломаешь. Почему `while` а не просто `for to` ?

Comment: почему  Application.ProcessMessages; плохая идея? согласен, имя ужасное, так, что уже испровляю! а self что бы перестраховаться. между while..do и for .. to разницы в быстродействии есть? (Junior)

Comment: `for to` лаконичнее на 2 строки и прямолинейнее в своей цели. `Application.ProcessMessages;` - простой пример, что случится если во время обработки пользователь нажмет на крестик закрытия программы? или поменяет выбранную строку? или 100500 других вещей которые он может сделать?

Comment: @KromStern может можно как то оптимизировать это? записей много и развертывание уровня занимает около минуты. Вот например если развернуть группы gr1.tableview1.DataController.Groups.FullExpand;, то обрабатывает мгновенно.

Comment: Не помню точно, но если у вашего `cxgrdbndtblvwcxgrd1DBBandedTableView1.DataController` есть `BeginUpdate` / `EndUpdate`, то они могут все очень сильно ускорить.

Comment: @KromStern вот так? на 10 сек быстрее. и программа во время выполнения не отвечает

Comment: Self.grTableViewBSD.DataController.BeginUpdate;
      try
        Self.grTableViewBSD.DataController.GotoFirst;
          for I := 1 to Self.odsbs.RecordCount do
          begin
            ARecord := TcxGridTableController(grGrid1Level1.GridView.Controller).FocusedRecord;
            TcxGridMasterDataRow(ARecord).Expand(True);
            Self.grTableViewBSD.DataController.GotoNext;
          end;
          Self.grTableViewBSD.DataController.GotoFirst;
       finally
       Self.grTableViewBSD.DataController.EndUpdate;
       end;

Comment: Да, так. А программа во время выполнения никак и не будет отвечать. Если хотите показать прогресс - делайте это отдельно.

Answer (score 0):

```
Self.grTableViewBSD.DataController.BeginUpdate;
Self.grTableViewBSD.ViewData.Expand(True);
Self.grTableViewBSD.DataController.EndUpdate;
self.grTableViewBSD.DataController.GotoFirst;
```

Comment: Вот пример без цикла.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ  - это вызвать ViewData.Expand метод с параметром False: `GridView.ViewData.Expand(False);`